# Как заставить ресурсы кешироваться?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, веб-сервер, кэширование

- **Я воспользовался сервисом** **[Google Page Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)** **для проверки скорости сайта**.
- Я думал, что все ресурсы сайта **автоматически кешируются** **в браузере** и задавать какие-то *параметры для кеша* на сервере **нет необходимости**, **но**
  *Гугл показывает обратное:*

1. **Name:** *core.js*
2. **Cache Life Time:** *none*
3. **Size:** *1kb*

**Каким образом я могу решить данную  проблему?**

**P.S.**

*Я использую 000webhost в качестве сервера*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если файл core.js ваш и у вас есть `.htaccess` - можете в него добавить эти строки:

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On

#по умолчанию кеш
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days"

# Включаем кэширование css, javascript и текстовых файлов на одну неделю
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"

</ifModule>
```

Comment: **Спасибо**  **вам**